# Save and load value for list of tkinter Entries in Python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have a relatively simple little tkinter GUI which has about 30 entry boxes that need to be filled out by the user multiple times. I would like to make this as painless as possible, and since many of the entries will be the same between sessions, it would simplify things greatly for the user if I could save the state of the entry boxes and simply reload the same contents in the next session.

This is pretty easy to do the ugly way - simple .get() the contents of each entry, save to a file, and .set() it back the next time. I am wondering if there is a more elegant way to do it, without having to .get() and .set() each entry individually every time - something like just pickling a list of entries in one shot. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could use something like what is described in Fredrik Lundh's [_Generating Tkinter User Interfaces from XML_](http://effbot.org/zone/element-tkinter.htm) to save and (re)load the entry forms as XML formatted data. Note that the `xml.etree.ElementTree` module has been part of Python standard library since version 2.5.

Comment: I'll look into it, thanks

Comment: How did make it in the end? :)

Comment: @Joe I took the ugly solution in the end, since it was a one time use application it wasn't worth putting in too much extra effort.

Comment: @KBriggs ok thanks, if you post your solution, i'll upvote it

Comment: @Joe, I don't think there's much point posting it since it would reauire a lot of explanation and is nowhere close to an MWE, but you can see the code here: https://github.com/shadowk29/cusumtools/blob/master/nanolog.py. The function you want is load_last()

Comment: @KBriggs Thank you!